# Filter web links extracted from a html website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to python. I have successfully extracted html links or a tags and entered them into a CSV file.

I am only getting an output of 2, 3 or 22 links, depending on what I try.

The website has website has 244 links and over half are duplicate's. The correct number of links that are not duplicates is 117.

This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import bs4, csv
search_link = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
r = requests.get(search_link)
raw_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
all_links = soup.find_all("a")
r.content

rem_dup = set()
for link in all_links:
    hrefs = str(link.get("href"))
    if hrefs.startswith('#http'):
        rem_dup.add(hrefs[1:])
    elif hrefs.endswith('.gov'):
    rem_dup.add(hrefs + '/')
    elif hrefs.startswith('/'):
        rem_dup.add('https://www.census.gov' + hrefs)
    else:
        rem_dup.add(hrefs)

filename = "Page_Links.csv"
f = open(filename, "w+")
f.write("LINKS\n")
f.write('https://www.census.gov')
f.close()
```

Comment: What do you get when you `print(len(rem_dum))` after the `for` loop?

Comment: NameError: name 'rem_dum' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, typo: `print(len(rem_dup))`.

Comment: 118, I think that works. Thanks!